# mysql bind address bind to localhost

Tags: mysql

I setup a remote database server on digital ocean. I use this server to connect different VPS to this server and save the data separately. This works very well. But I do not know how to connect properly via sequelPro to this server now, as I needed to adjust the my.cnf file on the server to adjust the bind address.

When I set the bind_address to 127.0.0.1 I can connect perfectly well to the server via this config:

[image]

But if I do this, I cannot connect anymore to the remote server from my other droplet, as the server IP of the DB VPS is now set to 127.0.0.1 and not to the remote server IP address.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try binding it to 0.0.0.0 which would mean bind to all addresses?

Comment: that worked! But isn't this unsecure?

Comment: It binds to all IP address. You want it to bind to public ip address, intranet ip address and local ip address and that is what it would do. Change the default port number to something large that people would keep guessing and that should help.

Comment: Also security is determined by the way you harden your application which is your database server. As long as you have strong password that should take care of your security concerns.

Comment: thank you! works very well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind it to `0.0.0.0` which binds to all addresses. Change the default port number to something large that people would keep guessing and that should help.

Also security is determined by the way you harden your application which is your database server. As long as you have strong password that should take care of your security concerns.